# Remove beginning of PHP string until it's 13 characters?

Tags: php

I have a variable that needs it's value's shortened until they are 13 characters.  It needs to chop off characters from the beginning of the string.  Is this built into PHP?

Answer (score 4):

The following should work for you:

```
$str = substr($str, -13);
```

Comment: I was just about to post the same...you beat me to it.

Answer (score 2):

The `substr` function is what you're looking for,

```
$text = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
$text = substr($text, -13);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`substr`](http://php.net/substr):

```
$v = substr($v, -13);
```